# error uploading file to parse from unity3D

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am using Parse for a game that I'm developing.
Everything is ok until I try to uplad a file, no matters his extension I always get this Error : "get_version can only be called from main thread"

URL=http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=764075parseError.png

and this is my script :

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Working at Parse is great!");
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("resume.txt", data);
            Task saveTask = file.SaveAsync();
            var player = new ParseObject ("FilesLibrary");
            player ["Number"] = 155;
            player ["Files"] = file;
            saveTask = player.SaveAsync();
```

I have tried to place this script in different places but I always get the same problem.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling this script from? I know you said you tried it in different places, what were those places?

Comment: I've tried it in the update function, button's OnClick event, couroutine, Queue<Action>; The thing is that I have this problem only if I try to push a file if I use any other data type it works without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the file is uploaded to Parse first, before you try to save it to the db object.

The Parse Unity documentation is not very good as it doesn't fit Unity's threading model. I would suggest using co-routines to do all your Parse calls.

I posted this on Unity Answers as well, but you get the idea..

```
// The file first needs to be uploaded to Parse before it can be saved to the object in the database
 ParseFile _playerFile;

 public void CreatePlayer()
 {
     StartCoroutine (UploadPlayerFile ((response) => {
         if(response == 1)
             StartCoroutine(CreateProjectAsync());                        
         else
             Debug.LogError("The file could not be uploaded");
     }));
 }        

 IEnumerator UploadPlayerFile(Action <int> callback)
 {
     var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (@"C:\myfile.jpg");
     _playerFile = new ParseFile ("file.jpg",  fileBytes, "image/jpeg");

     var saveTask = _playerFile.SaveAsync ();

     while (!saveTask.IsCompleted)
         yield return null;        

     if (saveTask.IsFaulted) {
         Debug.LogError ("An error occurred while uploading the player file : " + saveTask.Exception.Message);
         callback (-1);
     } else {            
         callback (1);
     }    
 }

 IEnumerator CreateProjectAsync()
 {        
     ParseObject player = new ParseObject ("Player");
     player ["Number"] = 111;
     player ["Files"] = _playerFile;

     var saveTask = player.SaveAsync ();

     while (!saveTask.IsCompleted)
         yield return null;        

     if (saveTask.IsFaulted) {
         Debug.LogError ("An error occurred while creating the player object : " + saveTask.Exception.Message);

     } else {    
         Debug.Log ("Player created successfully");
     }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need force your Parse queries to execute on `Main Thread`. you can achieve this by

```
public readonly static Queue<Action> ExecuteOnMainThread = new Queue<Action> ();
```

Add your query Method in this Queue. Like

```
ExecuteOnMainThread.Enqueue (() => {
                StartCoroutine (SaveData (ID, playerName)); });
```

In your `SaveData() Coroutine` you need to execute your Parse queries.

and finally:

```
void Update()
{
    while (ExecuteOnMainThread != null && ExecuteOnMainThread.Count > 0)
    {
        Action currentAction = ExecuteOnMainThread.Dequeue();
        if (currentAction != null) 
        {
            currentAction.Invoke ();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird, the same script works fine with unity 4.6 but not 5.1 !